# Uncaught ReferenceError: block is not defined

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to pass css code into my react javascript and I get the following error -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: block is not defined
```

Here is the relevant app.js code -

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <div className="sidebar content-box" style={{display: block}}>
        <ul className="nav">
            <AppList data={this.state.data} />
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the css found here -

https://github.com/VinceG/Bootstrap-Admin-Theme-3/blob/master/css/styles.css

it works fine if the code is in the HTML like so -

```
<div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Why are you putting it in `{{ }}` if you're not using any variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the prop `style` expects an object of key value pairs here, and remember your in js land so your `block` needs to be either a variable or a quoted string.

use `style={{display: "block"}}` instead